# Querying by Comparing to ObjectId

Tags: scala, mongodb, casbah

I have `val maxId = new ObjectId(...)` and I want to query something like this: `collection.find("_id" $lte maxId)`. This is a compilation failure since `ObjectId` doesn't include the appropriate trait `ValidDateOrNumericType`. How to properly query objects by comparing their ID?

In the Mongo shell this seems to be possible:

```
> db.test.find({"_id": {$lte: ObjectId("4e825d2f84ae30e970bc0f95")}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e82540684ae236af6e72177")}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e825baa84aea840b82e0278")}
...
>
```

Also with the Java driver it works:

```
query.put("_id", new BasicDBObject("$lte", new ObjectId("4e825d2f84ae30e970bc0f95")))
```

Is this doable with [Casbah](https://github.com/mongodb/casbah)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Casbah this can not be done, since [`ObjectId` does not convert to `ValidDateOrNumericType`](https://github.com/mongodb/casbah/blob/master/casbah-query/src/main/scala/Implicits.scala). I ended up using the Java API:

```
collection.find(new QueryBuilder().put("_id").lessThanEquals(maxId).get())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the comparison 'operator' as a method. To use it your ObjectId has to be on the left side of the comparison.

You can use the "pimp my library" to provide a implicit conversion to something that contains the comparison. (see this question [How does ‘1 * BigInt(1)’ work and how can I do the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647835/how-does-1-bigint1-work-and-how-can-i-do-the-same/7647856#7647856))

Or you can implement a trait which offers the desired functionality.

Comment: I don't understand how this would solve the issue which seems to be more on the MongoDB side of things?

Comment: Sorry I thought we were talking about a Scala problem.

Comment: Well, I guess it's somewhat specific to the Scala driver for MongoDB.